# Pandas delete row from dataframe if it is contained in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first one contains a multi-index of States names and Cities and columns with different data. On the other dataframe I have states and citie names. What I wanted to do is to remove from the first one any row that have the same state and city from the second dataframe. I tried using `isin`but it didn't work. I was thinking on creating a new column to do a comparison but I think I could do something that would be faster. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can't help you, there's no data here.

Comment: My code was really big, but @Scott Boston did a great job solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)])

idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list('ABCDEF'),index=idx1)

df1
     0
1 1  A
  2  B
  3  C
2 1  D
  2  E
  3  F

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=idx2)

df2

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

`isin` works:

```
df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]

     0
1 1  A
  2  B
2 3  F
```

Or "is not in":

```
df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]

     0
1 3  C
2 1  D
  2  E
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my mistake was that I forgot to add the first index in `df1.index.isin(df2.index)`. Now I see that to compare indexes it has to have that. Thank you so much.